# AttributeError: 'FakeFile' object has no attribute 'read_given_key'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-app-engine-python, dev-appserver-2

For some reason line 171 of [loaders.py](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/master/jinja2/loaders.py#L171) interprets the file object as a FakeFile

Type(f) returns class of type 'google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python.stubs.FakeFile'

**Code**

appengine_config.py

```
import os, sys
from google.appengine.ext import vendor


# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.


if os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
  sys.path.insert(0, 'lib.zip')
  vendor.add('lib')
else:
  vendor.add('C:\Code\App-Engine\cfc-melbourne-website\lib')
  if os.name == 'nt':
    os.name = None
    sys.platform = ''
    import re
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import stubs
    re_ = stubs.FakeFile._skip_files.pattern.replace('|^lib/.*', '')
    re_ = re.compile(re_)
    stubs.FakeFile._skip_files = re_
  sys.path.insert(0, 'lib')
sys.path.insert(0, 'lib')
```

Admin routes

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import render_template
from app.decorators.authentication import authenticate_admin
from app.admin.routes.conference_forms_routes import init_conference_forms


    def admin_blueprints(app):
        admin_routes = Blueprint("admin", __name__, template_folder='../../templates', static_folder='../../static')

        init_conference_forms(admin_routes)

        @admin_routes.route('/xxxx')
        def admin_landing():
            return render_template('admin/admin_landing.html')

        app.register_blueprint(admin_routes)
```

Running a Flask Application gives me the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'FakeFile' object has no attribute 'read_given_key'
  File "lib\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "lib\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "lib\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "lib\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "lib\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Code\App-Engine\cfc-melbourne-website\app\main\routes\home_routes.py", line 22, in main
    return render_template('main.html')
  File "lib\flask\templating.py", line 133, in render_template
    return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "lib\jinja2\environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "lib\jinja2\environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "lib\jinja2\environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "lib\jinja2\loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "lib\flask\templating.py", line 57, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "lib\flask\templating.py", line 82, in _get_source_fast
    return loader.get_source(environment, template)
  File "lib\jinja2\loaders.py", line 175, in get_source
    contents = f.read_given_key().decode(self.encoding)
```

Not sure why this is happening.

loaders.py function where it bombs

```
def get_source(self, environment, template):
    pieces = split_template_path(template)
    for searchpath in self.searchpath:
        filename = path.join(searchpath, *pieces)
        f = open_if_exists(filename)
        if f is None:
            continue
        try:
            contents = f.read_given_key().decode(self.encoding)
        finally:
            f.close()

        mtime = path.getmtime(filename)

        def uptodate():
            try:
                return path.getmtime(filename) == mtime
            except OSError:
                return False
        return contents, filename, uptodate
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
```

Contents of app.yaml

```
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
- ^(.*/)?.*/node_modules/.*$
- ^(.*/)?.*/client_libs/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\.bowerrc$
- ^(.*/)?\.bower.json$
- ^(.*/)?\.gulpfile.js$
- ^(.*/)?\.package.json$
- ^(.*/)?\.requirements.txt$
- ^(.*/)?\.upload.bat$
```

Comment: What is FakeFile? Could you provide more details please? Some code etc?